# Error: Cannot find module - Local path of image won't load in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm making a movie library using electron.js + vue.js with json as my database. All data has been loaded from the database except the image path inside won't load.

I tried to use require() to load the local path of the image but it always throws me an error of Error in render: Error: Cannot find module file path.

```html
<v-card v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id" class="pa-5">
      <v-card-title primary-title>
        {{ movie.id }} - {{ movie.title }}
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        {{ movie.year }}
      </v-card-text>
      <v-img :src="getImage(movie.poster)" />
</v-card>
```

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      movies: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      axios.get('db.json').then(res => {
        return this.movies = res.data.movies
      })
    },
    getImage(poster) {
      return poster ? require(`${poster}`) : ''
    }
  },
  async created() {
    this.fetchData()
  }
};
```

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Aladdin",
      "year": 2019,
      "poster": "../../../posters/aladdin_2019.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Alita Battle Angel",
      "year": 2019,
      "poster": "../../../posters/alita.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What will happen if you try to use `v-if` condition in `v-img`?

Comment: Adding v-if in v-img?

Comment: Yes, try that. `v-if="movie.poster"`

Comment: It loads the data normally but still, the image won't appear.

Comment: Check your path. Try to put hardcoded path and see what will happen

Comment: If that won't work out, try the trick `require(""+poster)`

Comment: I also tried the hardcoded path `<v-img :src="require(../../../posters/aladdin_2019.jpg)" />`. It works, though it only appears both for those two titles. I want it to load those images to their respective titles.

Comment: Thank u so much. `require(""+poster)` works! I would like to know how it happens.

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your methods inside `require` use empty string to concatenate your path and get string as a result, which `require` expects:

```
getImage(poster) {
  return poster ? require("" + poster) : ''
}
```

You can find more information about that if you read [require with expression](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) of the official docs.